# How to interact between a smart contract written in Solidity from substrate pallet?

Tags: pallet, solidity

Can it be possible to interact solidity smart contract from substrate pallet?

Comment: You want to make backend for solidity smart contract as pallet on Rust?

Comment: yes @ShubhamGupta

Comment: Wouldn't this be [`pallet_evm`](https://docs.rs/pallet-evm/latest/pallet_evm/)?

Comment: @Ganesh11 you can develop it but I didn't understand why you want to do that, if you want an EVM contract on substrate just use frontier so that you can have the EVM functionalities on your chain.